# AWS-SDK (lightsail API) vue.js CORS issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aws-sdk, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to build a small vue.js app that uses aws-sdk to get all the Lightsial instances. However, I keep getting this error.

```
:8081/#/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://lightsail.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here  is my vue component script

```js
import { AmplifyEventBus } from 'aws-amplify-vue'
import { components } from 'aws-amplify-vue'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import Lightsail from 'aws-sdk/clients/lightsail'
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';


export default {
components: {
    AWS, Lightsail
  },
  data() {
    return {
     
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  var myCredentials = 
    {
      accessKeyId : '***************',
      secretAccessKey : '****************'
    }

  AWS.config.update({
    credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
  });

    var lightsail = new AWS.Lightsail();
    lightsail.getInstances(function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });




  }

}
```

I am also using aws-amplify-vue in this app for user authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply because current release of <[aws-sdk-js](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/sdk-for-browser/)> does **not allows CORS** for Lightsail API.

The [official document](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/0b4018ab9c6a1953af186fdbfcf762086ac0e52a/SERVICES.md) informs that clearly.

*EDIT:* A completely wrong answer written by another user has been deleted after I added a comment to that. So I removed the words "Right answer" from my answer. Thanks for [your](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4257303/) quick action.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, it should be a CORS problem. Here is a similar thread in which some workaround are mentioned. Could your go to check if it works in your scenario?

[Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)